# Поиск вложенных максимальных значений postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Предположим есть такая таблица (после join'ов)

```
Фрукт        | Сироп      | Вкус_фрукта | Вкус_сиропа  |
Яблоко       | Брусничный |  2          |   1          |
Яблоко       | Вишневый   |  2          |   2          |
Яблоко       | Персиковый |  2          |   3          |
Слива        | Брусничный |  1          |   1          |
....
```

Выборка `select * from table where table.вкус_фрукта = (select max(table.вкус_фрукта) from table);`

Результатом выполнения мы получим все яблоки (т.к они имеют один и тот же рейтинг) и разные сиропы.
Вопрос: Как из результирующего списка получить максимальное значение сиропа, т.е Яблоко + Персиковый.
Таких "вложенных максимумов" будет несколько. Т.е основной вопрос как находить такие максимумы с N вложенностями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Вкус_фрукта" DESC) rnk
          FROM src_table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Вкус_сиропа" DESC) rnk
          FROM cte1
          WHERE rnk = 1 )
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Ну или сразу

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Вкус_фрукта" DESC, "Вкус_сиропа" DESC) rnk
         FROM src_table )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, сегодня попробую и отпишусь по результатам.

Comment: @LeFroys чё пробовать-то? online fiddles всегда под рукой, создать таблицу с данными и проверить запрос - делов на три минуты.

Comment: Да, такое решение помогло, спасибо.